# SQL vs Google Hours per year

Tags: sql, hour

Which is more correct?

SQL:

```
select datediff(HOUR, '2013-01-01 00:00:00 AM','2013-12-31 11:59:59 PM') = 8759
```

Google:
https://www.google.com/search?q=hours+ina+year&oq=hours+in+a+year  = 8765.81

Comment: More correct for what purpose?

Comment: financial calculations.

Comment: Not all years have the same number of days. Plus watch out for rounding/off-by-one errors in your query.

Comment: are you saying that datediff isn't smart enough to handle leap years, et al?

Comment: Google shows average year (or maybe astronomical year) I guess. Certainly, one year should contain the whole number of hours...

Comment: I'm saying no such thing. I'm saying your query returns the number of hours (+/-1) in 2013. Google isn't returning that.

Comment: It really should be 8760 hours because you are rounding down. Obviously, number of hours in a year should be divisible by 24. This is simply 356 days...

Comment: Wolfram alpha says 8760 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here Google calculator is using the [Tropical year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_year), which is the time the earth takes to orbit the sun. If you disregard our calendar, there are 365.24 24-hour days in a year, which is useful if you want “year” to have a constant value you can use as a unit.

You probably don’t want to disregard our calendar, so there are 365 or 366 days in a year.

Comment: So, is datediff smart enough to handle leap years then?

Comment: @user1013388 yes, it should be. Why don't you try - just enter a leap year there and see for yourself.

Comment: "the time the sun takes to orbit the earth" -1 for this from a physicist.

Answer (score 0):

They are showing you different things.

Google is showing you the astronomical year - time it takes Earth to turn around the Sun once (matches the number from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year)).

SQL is showing you the right number, apart from the fact that you have a rounding error (because you miss one last minute). It should be 8760 which is 24*365.